# Server side validation for Cloudfare Turnstile reCaptcha

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

I am adding CF Turnstile recaptcha to my asp.net core web api for our contact us form and I am curious what IP address I should be using for this verification process. My code is as follows:

```
            var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    { "secret", reCaptchaKey },
                    { "response", customerInquiry.Token }
                };

        var postContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(dictionary);

        HttpResponseMessage recaptchaResponse = null;
        string stringContent = "";

        // Call recaptcha api and validate the token
        using (var http = new HttpClient())
        {
            recaptchaResponse = await http.PostAsync("https://challenges.cloudflare.com/turnstile/v0/siteverify", postContent);
            stringContent = await recaptchaResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
```

The example code on CF shows the following for their node.js ( I assume) implementation:

```
formData.append('secret', SECRET_KEY);
formData.append('response', token);
formData.append('remoteip', ip);
```

Comment: Docs also say `const ip = request.headers.get('CF-Connecting-IP');`; so the ip variable will be the IP address of the visitor. If your web app is behind a CF proxied sub-domain, you can get that with `HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("CF-Connecting-IP", out var visitorIp);`

Answer (score 0):

That parameter is optional according to the Turnstile docs. However, if you wish to pass it, you could use:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "secret", reCaptchaKey },
    { "response", customerInquiry.Token },
    { "remoteip", Request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString() 
};
```